# How to print the complete SQL Statement with the OCI_GetSql function?

Tags: c++, mysql, oracle-call-interface

I am trying to print the string value of the sql statement generated by `OCI_Prepare` function, the problem is that the value of bound parameters are not printed.

My code:

```
OCI_Prepare (mStatement, "DELETE FROM MyTable WHERE Column1 = :Column1Value");
OCI_BindString(mStatement, ":Column1Value", myBuffer, 30);

OCI_Execute(mStatement);
std::string sqlstr = OCI_GetSql(mStatement);
printf("sql: %s\n", sqlstr.c_str());
OCI_Commit(cn);
```

output:

> sql: DELETE FROM MyTable WHERE Column1 = :Column1Value

How can I print the final SQL statement?

Answer (score 1):

This is the final statement. In prepared statements parameters are separated from the query and processed by database engine separately, so we get sql injection protection and processing speed up since engine does not need to re-parse queries that differ only in parameters.

Unfortunately there is no builtin method to get formatted parameters bound to statement in ocilib. But you can easily find someone's else implementation, e.g. have a look at [ido2db_oci_print_binds](https://git.icinga.org/?p=icinga-core.git;a=blob;f=module/idoutils/src/db.c#l7107). Hope this helps.